# Data Sharing between Client and Server Two Way

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please solve my query

One of my Silverlight application is running.
This Application is using one central database (sql server 2008) and three other client databases (sql server 2008) at other server locations.
Our requirement is with minor changing or without changing in Silverlight application
When we make change in central database (insert update and delete in multiple tables) these change 
Automatically occurs in all client database.
and when any change made in any client database all client as well as central database should be updated automatically.

For this I read some about Sync Framework and SQL Server 2008 Change Tracking.
But i have no idea about how will I do this.
Please help me. How can we achieve this.